# how to pair rows of a data frame with respect of a group?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, pairing

I have a big data. a column of text and a column of id.

```
column        id
hello world    1
dinner         1
father         1
hi             1
work/related   2
summer         2
```

I want to pair words whose have the same id and followed each other

output:

```
 new column        
hello world ,dinner   
dinner ,father         
father, hi  
work/related , summer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use str.cat to concat every 2 consecutive rows in a group.

```
 df=df.assign(newcolumn=df.groupby('id')['column'].apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(x.shift(-1),sep=','))).dropna()



     column    id         newcolumn
0    helloworld   1    helloworld,dinner
1        dinner   1        dinner,father
2        father   1            father,hi
4  work/related   2  work/related,summer
```

Comment: The last element of each group is mapped to something weird

Comment: What do you mean, I just reproduced your expected result. Didnt I?

Comment: in my code the last element of each group is mapped to something strange! I can't find where did they come from. in the output why you missed hi after father? in `column`

Comment: This should work, happy to help further if given more info.

Comment: please put `hi` after father in your output. (column before id)

Comment: Oh I see the last element is mapped to something which is dropped by `na`! cool I got it